# German ß in tikzpicture with text decoration - Package inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, german, utf8

I wonder why I can't use the ß directly at this point: `decoration={text={heißer Dampf}`. If I do that, pdflatex throws me an error: "Package inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte". I can't understand why it doesn't work with the decoration texts. The workaround is to replace the ß with {\ ss}, but it's unsatisfactory. What is the problem with the implementation of the decorative texts and UTF8?

```
   \documentclass{standalone}
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%Die Textdateien sind mit Unicode-Kodierung
   \usepackage{pgf,tikz}
   \usetikzlibrary{mindmap,shadows,positioning,fit,petri,backgrounds,shapes,arrows,through,calc,decorations.text,decorations.markings,intersections,fpu,circuits.ee.IEC,babel}
        
        
    \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            [node distance=3cm and 3cm,on grid,auto,align=center,thick,
            Schritt/.style={rectangle,
                draw=black,inner sep=5pt,
                execute at begin node=\hspace{0pt},%allow first word to break
            },
            Pfeil/.style={>=latex, ultra thick,->,bend angle=35, bend left, postaction=decorate,
                decoration={raise=4pt, text align=center, text along path}}
            ]
            \begin{scope}
                \node (Mitte) {};%Hilfsnode für die Mitte
                \node[Schritt] (Schritt1) [above=of Mitte] {großer Dampferzeuger};
                \node[Schritt] (Schritt2) [right=of Mitte] {Turbine};
                \node[Schritt] (Schritt3) [below=of Mitte] {Kondensator};
                \node[Schritt] (Schritt4) [left=of Mitte]  {Kesselwasser-\\speisepumpe};
                
                \draw [Pfeil,decoration={text={hei{\ss}er Dampf}}]          (Schritt1) to (Schritt2);
                \draw [Pfeil,decoration={text={warmer Dampf},reverse path}] (Schritt2) to (Schritt3);
                \draw [Pfeil,decoration={text={Wasser},reverse path}]       (Schritt3) to (Schritt4);
                \draw [Pfeil,decoration={text={Wasser}}]                    (Schritt4) to (Schritt1);
                
            \end{scope}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

decorations works token by token, and as the ß consists of two bytes in utf8 it is split. It works if you protect it with a brace:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%Die Textdateien sind mit Unicode-Kodierung
   \usepackage{pgf,tikz}
   \usetikzlibrary{mindmap,shadows,positioning,fit,petri,backgrounds,shapes,arrows,through,calc,decorations.text,decorations.markings,intersections,fpu,circuits.ee.IEC,babel}


    \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            [node distance=3cm and 3cm,on grid,auto,align=center,thick,
            Schritt/.style={rectangle,
                draw=black,inner sep=5pt,
                execute at begin node=\hspace{0pt},%allow first word to break
            },
            Pfeil/.style={>=latex, ultra thick,->,bend angle=35, bend left, postaction=decorate,
                decoration={raise=4pt, text align=center, text along path}}
            ]
            \begin{scope}
                \node (Mitte) {};%Hilfsnode für die Mitte
                \node[Schritt] (Schritt1) [above=of Mitte] {großer Dampferzeuger};
                \node[Schritt] (Schritt2) [right=of Mitte] {Turbine};
                \node[Schritt] (Schritt3) [below=of Mitte] {Kondensator};
                \node[Schritt] (Schritt4) [left=of Mitte]  {Kesselwasser-\\speisepumpe};

                \draw [Pfeil,decoration={text={hei{ß}er Dampf}}]          (Schritt1) to (Schritt2);
                \draw [Pfeil,decoration={text={warmer Dampf},reverse path}] (Schritt2) to (Schritt3);
                \draw [Pfeil,decoration={text={Wasser},reverse path}]       (Schritt3) to (Schritt4);
                \draw [Pfeil,decoration={text={Wasser}}]                    (Schritt4) to (Schritt1);

            \end{scope}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Or use `\ss` instead of `ß`.

Comment: @HenriMenke the question already mentions \ss.

Comment: @HenriMenke the OP had `\ss` in the question but wanted to use the character. (pgf could actually detect that the token it has stripped off is `\UTFviii@two@octets` and grab the next two bytes as if they were braced...

Comment: It is still unsatisfactory. It doesn't matter whether I write {ß} or {\ ss}. Fact ist the ß needs special treatment. I cannot see why it is technically possible to write the ß directly in connection with a normal label `{großer Dampferzeuger}` and, on the other hand, I have to make sure that I treat the ß specially with the text decorations. I haven't tried it, but it will probably be similarly problematic with other special characters: äöüá and so on. What is the technical reason why you cannot implement this simple text input within the text decorations? Is it a decoration library problem?

Comment: @Michael.H As David wrote, it should be technical possible, but someone must implement it. Make a feature request at the tikz/pgf github. Beside this: it is not simple text input, ß is a rather complicated command with pdflatex. With lualatex where ß is a simply char your code would work out of the box.

Comment: When the possibility with Input-UTF8 was introduced, I was very grateful that the text input was so nicely simplified. It was not clear to me that current packages or libraries still do not support this consistently. It should be in everyone's interest to support this standard everywhere. I am amazed that there are still treadmills in this, for me, absolute foundation. It is a disaster for the writing flow when I have to mask special characters. That Americans get along without special characters is understandable, I have all of the others on my side.

Comment: @Michael.H yes, it would be nice if it worked everywhere. But you are using an 8-bit engine from the last century, and tweaking it to use an encoding from this century is hard work and while you can now (after some people spent quite a lot of their free time to get this working) use these chars in labels and file names and other places, there are still places where it fails. If you think this is a disaster then use a modern unicode engine like lualatex.

Comment: I would like to emphasize that my choice of words "disaster" relates to the flow of writing. Not on the LaTeX system itself. I am very grateful that there is even a professional opportunity for writing demanding texts. I write physical worksheets every day. If the use of special characters (German words are full of them) breaks up my output, then that's really not nice. I thank everyone for Your comments, in special @UlrikeFischer.